# Use a base class as the return type in ApiController

Tags: xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api

Using the ASP.NET WebApi 4 RC, is it possible to have an ApiController's return type be a base class and actually return instances of derived classes? Trying to do this now results in an internal server error (500) when returning xml. Returning json using this method works correctly.

```
public class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Base> Get()
    {
        return new Derived[] { 
            new Derived(){ Message="test"},
            new Derived(){ Message="another"}
        };
    }
}
```

It would seem that the XML serialization is what's throwing the error but all I can see is the generic 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the knowntype serialization hint:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownType(typeof(Derived))]
public class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you realize that this question is a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate (...) :-)

Comment: @FilipW so which question is the end all be all with hundreds of upvotes and .NET expert answers weighing in... i cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it programmatically

```
    private static Type[] GetKnownType()
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        var knownTypes = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
        {
            knownTypes.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof (BaseResponse)).ToArray());
        }
        return knownTypes.ToArray();
    }
```

Do remember your child class MUST have a default constructor else you will get runtime serialization error.